# PHP Redirect Issues with mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect but my code has PHP and MYSQL code and when I try to redirect it says that the ID for what it is trying to redirect to is not there.

Here is my code I want to redirect:

`<a href="game.php?id=<?php echo $conn->insert_id; ?>">`
This code works if you click on it but I need it to auto send you to the page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: User header("page url you want to redirect to");

Comment: if you want this type of output than you can use script and meta tag